# Display desktop, dock and menu bar on both screens

Tags: display, macos

I have a Macbook Pro connected with a secondary screen. I would like **both** screens to have a dock, a desktop (see the desktop items on both screens) and menu bars. In other words, almost as if I had two Macbooks next to eachother.

Right now, I do have the menu bar on both, but I can't find any option to display desktop items on both, as well as the dock.

Is this possible?

OSX El Capitan 10.11.1.

Comment: Do you want your other desktop to have the same icons or do you want it to have, say, the ones that didn't fit on #1?

Comment: @GhostLyrics I'm fine either way really.